# Dynamic OpenGraph Meta Tags will not Parse

Tags: facebook, comments, meta-tags

I have having trouble getting Facebook to recognize my OpenGraph meta tags for the Social Comments plugin. I have thoroughly researched this matter here and on Google.

I have tried setting content-length header as was suggested in a few other instances of this issue. I have also tried making sure that the fb:comments href was exactly the same as the og:url. None of these are allowing Facebook to recognize my meta tags.

Page Tab URL:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Telenova-IP-Services/287547201338150?sk=app_348971505174676

URL For Debugger:
http://apps3.ionflo.com/photocontest/index.php?type=restaurant&id=287547201338150-IPUTI8K7EGYMSTBU

FILE /index.php:

```
97 $cody = array(
98         'title' => $TitleShare,
99         'description' => $DescriptionShare,
100         'type' => 'restaurant');

117         <!-- Open Graph meta tags -->
118         <meta property="fb:app_id" content="348971505174676" />
119         <meta property="og:site_name" content="Test Site Name"/>
120         <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $AbsoluteURL; ?>index.php?type=    <?php echo $params['type']; ?>&id=<?php echo $PageID . '-' . $CommentRandomVal; ?>"/>
121         <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $cody['title']; ?>"/>
122         <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $cody['description']; ?>"/>
123         <meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo $cody['type']; ?>"/>
124         <meta property="og:locale" content="<?php echo $params['locale']; ?>"/>
125         <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $AbsoluteURL; ?>images/facebook.png"/>
```

FILE: include/home.php

```
24          <fb:comments href="<?php echo $AbsoluteURL; ?>index.php?type=<?php echo     $params['type']; ?>&id=<?php echo $PageID . '-' . $CommentRandomVal; ?>" num_posts="3000"     width="800">
```

For a full copy of the code, please see:

http //apps3.ionflo.com/photocontest/index.bak

http //apps3.ionflo.com/photocontest/include/home.bak

Please let me know if I am missing any other useful information, I will be glad to update the post.

Cheers,

Cody

Answer (score 0):

URL did not contain correct PageID to pull meta tags.

Solved by ensuring we were passing the PageID correctly into the page as a get variable

E.G. ?PageID=************

Cheers.